# How to deal with multiple request_method?

Tags: php, session, methods, get, request

My PHP page can receive the same data from two differents pages, the first one send it using GET, and the second with sessions. How can I make this thing work ?

```
//$var = empty;

//$_GET['id'] = empty;


//User come from page1.php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {

$var = $_GET['data'];

}

else {

//User come from page2.php

$var = $_SESSION['data'];

}
```

Comment: `GET` is the "normal" method to request a page; how does the visitor get from `page2.php` to your page?

Comment: thanks you made me realise I can do both with GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (array_key_exists('data', $_GET)) {
    $var = $_GET['data'];
} else {
    $var = $_SESSION['data'];
}
```

Comment: This is not the right answer. OP asked the request comes from two pages.`page1.php` & `page2.php`, so your approach only checks the `data` and not the pages.

Comment: I understood the question to ask how to make it work with different pages that used either method. I preferred GET data over SESSION data due to the OP's if statement order. If you need to lock down the method depending on the page it would be better to have the specific code on the individual pages rather than an if else statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two pages, `page1.php` and `page2.php` and you want to know at first hand which page it is, and what is the `?data=` value... then this will do the trick.

```
<?php

$data = (isset($_GET['data']) && !empty($_GET['data'])) ? $_GET['data'] : '';
if($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] === 'page1.php'){

    $var = $data; 

}else if($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] === 'page2.php'){

    $var = $_SESSION['data'];

}
```